# Trying to center a div --- missing : after property id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to center an appended div, however I keep on getting this error:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

specifically after the `10)`.
Here's my code:

```
$("#infobox").css({marginTop:parseInt(($("#content").height() / 2) -("#infobox").height() / 2), 10) + 'px'});
```

I tried doing `10);` but haven't gotten rid of it.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `)` too much. `-("#infobox")` looks wrong as well, but it's not a syntax error. You don't need `parseInt` here btw.

Comment: Thanks, what about `("#infobox")` looks wrong? And which `)` do I remove?

Comment: I assume it's supposed to be `$("#infobox")` and you can remove any of the parenthesis coming after `/ 2`. Parenthesis must be balanced. A good editor should highlight which parenthesis matches another.

Comment: Hmmmm, but it _is_ `$("#infobox")`. I'm not sure what it's showing you. Thanks about the paranthesis, I will work on it! :)

Comment: I'm talking about the second one, not the first one.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm so blind :) Thanks@!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#infobox").css({
    marginTop: (parseInt($("#content").height(), 10) / 2) - (parseInt($("#infobox").height(), 10) / 2) + 'px'
});
```

Comment: `.height` returns an integer. `parseInt` is not necessary here.

Comment: @FelixKling - good point, but it doesn't hurt either ;). For the OP, here's a version without the parseInt: `marginTop: ($("#content").height() / 2) - ($("#infobox").height() / 2) + 'px'`